# can not make this regex pattern work in "very magic" mode

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to construct a regex pattern to match characters inside two `#` characters. For example:

```
#abc#bc#cd#
```

I would like to match `abc`, `bc` and `cd`. The following regex without using magic mode works as expected:

```
\(#\)\@<=.\{-\}\(#\)\@=
```

But when I try to use the `very magic` mode, I can not make the regex pattern right. Here is what I have come up with:

```
\v(#)\@<=.{-}(#)\@=
```

and it does not work (matches nothing). Can you point out what is wrong with my regex pattern?

Comment: It's very magic, every character other than 0-9a-zA-Z_ have special meaning. check `:h /\v`

Comment: I have read the doc but can find any related part. Do you mean `#` has special meaning? I can not find the doc on this.

Comment: well, why don't you use default magic mode, if it works? BTW: your regex in very magic mode needs to look like this: `\v(#)@<=.{-}(#)@=`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, thanks for the regex pattern. I do not know we have to drop the backslash in look around regex in very magic mode. It seems that this is not documented. What do you mean by `default magic mode`? I use very magic mode because it is more like Perl regex syntax.

Comment: of course this is documented: `:h /\v`